# Getting extent (bounds) of each feature using Fiona

Tags: python, geometry, features, extents, fiona

I was looking in Fiona to get for each feature its extent but I didn't find how.

I have try to far to do something like below

```py
import fiona

with fiona.open('countries/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp', 'r') as source:
    for f in source:
        geom = f['geometry']
        print geom
```

I was expecting to get a method for this at the f variable level. After some documentation reading, I've seen that f is a pure python record. So at the end, how with Fiona can I get the extent (or bounding box) of each feature geometry?

PS: I already know the pure GDAL/OGR python solution so I expect a Fiona solution please.

Comment: I would be really interested in seeing the OGR python solution.  I'm going through the documentation, and it looks like extents for layers and features are handled differently in OGR.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
def explode(coords):
    """Explode a GeoJSON geometry's coordinates object and yield coordinate tuples.
    As long as the input is conforming, the type of the geometry doesn't matter."""
    for e in coords:
        if isinstance(e, (float, int, long)):
            yield coords
            break
        else:
            for f in explode(e):
                yield f

def bbox(f):
    x, y = zip(*list(explode(f['geometry']['coordinates'])))
    return min(x), min(y), max(x), max(y)
```

Comment: Just in case it's not obvious: the approach above works for deserialized GeoJSON generally and isn't limited to use with Fiona.

Comment: I made a slight change to use ESRI's json and this solved one of my problems as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

You need to use the function `shape` of [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html):

```
from shapely.geometry import shape
c = fiona.open("ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp")
# first record
country = c.next()
print "country name :",country['properties']['NAME']
country name : Aruba
# shape(country['geometry']) -> shapely geometry
print "bounds:", shape(country['geometry']).bounds
bounds: (-70.062408006999874, 12.417669989000046, -69.876820441999939, 12.632147528000104)
```

Comment: I've accepted @sgillies answer because no lib dependency but I appreciate also your answer. Thanks

Comment: It does Thomas, but there you go, it's just not implicit!

Comment: As of Fiona 2.0, use `country = next(iter(c)` for `Collection.__next__() is buggy`.

Answer (score 0):

Great answers above, just want to add that using `rasterio` instead of `shapely` you can do

```
import fiona
import rasterio
src = fiona.open("ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp")
# first record
feature = src.next()
bounds = rasterio.features.bounds(feature['geometry'])
print("bounds:", bounds)
```

I use this to check if a feature is within the extent of a raster.