# How can I get a map image from an ArcGIS mapserver centered on a single feature?

Tags: python, arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api

I have a Python program that is *not* using arcpy. I need to get an image from a mapservice centered on a single feature using the REST api.

I can call the export method to get a map image:

```
http://<server>/arcgis/rest/services/<name>/MapServer/export?bbox=<bounds>&f=image
```

I can also query the mapservice layer using a where clause and get the feature geometry (in my case, it's going to be a polygon feature).

Without using arcpy, is there an *easy* way to take the polygon's geometry, get a rectangular extent to generate the bounding box necessary to call the export?

What would be ideal is if I could just say "Give me a map image centered on a feature from a layer defined by this where clause" but, unless I'm missing something, you can't do this in one step. Neither can I figure out how to do a Query on a layer and get the extent back instead of just the feature geometry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use my [restapi](https://github.com/Bolton-and-Menk-GIS/restapi) module.  It is very simple to do these kinds of things:

```
import restapi
import os

url = 'http://gis.mda.state.mn.us/arcgis/rest/services/MN_Agriculture_EAB_Detection/MapServer'

# reference map service
mapService = restapi.MapService(url)

# reference quarantine county layer so we can get a single feature
quarantines = mapService.layer('emerald ash borer quarantines') # could also just use the service id of 3

# query this to get a single feature
fs = quarantines.query(where="COUNTYNAME = 'Hennepin'")

featureGeom = restapi.Geometry(fs) # will grab the first polygon

# now export map png
png = r'C:\TEMP\test_export.png'
r = mapService.export(png, bbox=featureGeom.envelope(), bboxSR=mapService.spatialReference)
os.startfile(png)
```

This module does **NOT** require arcpy, but will use it if available. Otherwise it uses open source alternatives.

Comment: Awesome. I'll take a look and approve the answer if it works for me. Meanwhile, I adapted some code from here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90553/fiona-get-each-feature-extent-bounds and got it working in a brute force sorta way (after adapting this code to use ESRI json instead of GeoJSON).